# If it possible accelerate From-Where-Select method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two var of code:

first:

```
struct pair_fiodat {string fio; string dat;}
List<pair_fiodat> list_fiodat = new List<pair_fiodat>();
// list filled 200.000 records, omitted.
foreach(string fname in XML_files)
{
// get FullName and Birthday from file. Omitted.
var usersLookUp = list_fiodat.ToLookup(u => u.fio, u => u.dat); // create map
    var dates = usersLookUp[FullName];
    if (dates.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var dt in dates)
        {
            if (dt == BirthDate) return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and second:

```
struct pair_fiodat {string fio; string dat;}
List<pair_fiodat> list_fiodat = new List<pair_fiodat>();
// list filled 200.000 records, omitted.
foreach(string fname in XML_files)
{
// get FullName and Birthday from file. Omitted.
    var members = from s in list_fiodat where s.fio == FullName & s.dat == Birthdate select s;
    if (members.Count() > 0 return true;
}
```

They make the same job - searching user by name and birthday.
The first one work very quick.
The second is very slowly (10x-50x)
Tell me please if it possible accelerate the second one?
I mean may be the list need in special preparing?
I tried sorting: list_fiodat_sorted = list_fiodat.OrderBy(x => x.fio).ToList();, but...

Comment: 1. How did you measure? Did you use [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) ? If not: Do it. 2. Instead of `members.Count() > 0)` , I'd use `members.Any()`.

Comment: No need to use any benchmarks still as 1st var worked < 1 sec and 2nd 50-100 sec.

Comment: Did you only measure the foreach loop? Or in First snippet the creation of the map, too? I mean the first one is basically a lookup which should be near O(1) and the second is O(n).

Comment: What happens in the second example if you use a class instead of a struct?

Comment: Just for the record: You always searched for the same name and birthday, when measuring right?

Comment: I tried simplifie text for publishing here, sorry :-) I think it is bad idea...

Comment: I use the same list in both cases. I search the same Names (read from XML file)

Comment: Creation map don't take time. Less a second too.

Comment: You could try if using method syntax for the linq makes a difference, but I actually doubt that. Did you have a look what it gets lowered to? Maybe that's bringing some light into this?

Comment: ^^ Tried it, changing syntax results in same outcome.

Comment: Did you edit the first snippet? Now it seems you create the same lookup in each iteration??

Comment: Wait a second... `if (dates.Count() > 0)` - Ithink that should be a `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dates))`. And `foreach (var dt in dates)` shouldn't do what you think it does. Is this the _actual_ code, you are using? I get the feeling there is something lost in shortening.

Comment: Yes it is not actual code now, sorry... Will remake it.

Comment: If both versions work, and version 1 is faster, you can optimize version 2 by changing it into version 1 ! Why don't you do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skip your first test and change Count() to Any() (count iterate all list while any stop when there are an element)

```
public bool Test1(List<pair_fiodat> list_fiodat)
{
    foreach (string fname in XML_files)
    {
        var members = from s in list_fiodat 
            where s.fio == fname & s.dat == BirthDate
            select s;
        if (members.Any())
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you want optimize something, you must leave comfortable things that offer the language to you because usually this things are not free, they have a cost.
For example, for is faster than foreach. Is a bit more ugly, you need two sentences to get the variable, but is faster. If you iterate a very big collection, each iteration sum.
LINQ is very powerfull and it's wonder work with it, but has a cost. If you change it for another "for", you save time.

```
public bool Test2(List<pair_fiodat> list_fiodat)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < XML_files.Count; i++)
    {
        string fname = XML_files[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < list_fiodat.Count; j++)
        {
            var s = list_fiodat[j];

            if (s.fio == fname & s.dat == BirthDate)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

With normal collections there aren't difference and usually you use foeach, LINQ... but in extreme cases, you must go to low level.

In your first test, ToLookup is the key. It takes a long time. Think about this: you are iterating all your list, creating and filling the map. It's bad in any case but think about the case in which the item you are looking for is at the start of the list: you only need a few iterations to found it but you spend time in each of the items of your list creating the map. Only in the worst case, the time is similar and always worse with the map creation due to the creation itself.

The map is interesting if you need, for example, all the items that match some condition, get a list instead found a ingle item. You spend time creating the map once, but you use the map many times and, in each time, you save time (map is "direct access" against the for that is "sequencial").